# Rust Workspaces do not respect individual project targets defined in .cargo/config.toml

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Consider the following project directory:

```
root/
├──project_one/
│  ├──.cargo/
│  │    └──config.toml
│  ├──Cargo.toml
│  └──target.json
└──Cargo.toml
```

- `Cargo.toml` is the workspace manifest with `members = [ "project_one" ]`
- `project_one/Cargo.toml` is the project manifest
- `project_one/avr-atmega328p.json` defines target properties used by rustc(?)
- `root/project_one/.cargo/config.toml` listing `target = "target.json"` under `[build]`

#### Problem

`project_one` does not compile using the configured target unless I delete `root/Cargo.toml`.
The build fails with an error message indicating that information for a correct target platform is missing (`error: language item required, but not found: 'eh_personality'`).

#### Potential Solution

At the time of writing there has been a *very* recent PR merged into the rust-lang master branch: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/9030

Are there any other solutions to avoid having to wait for a fix?